# An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, macos-mojave

While executing `sudo bundle install` I am getting the following error.
Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/madhakul/Documents/Inshort/puurna/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2
for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/madhakul/Documents/Inshort/puurna/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out

> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler
> cannot continue.
> Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
roo was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on

After going through a few help materials, I have installed Developer Tools for MacOS 10.14 Mojave, but still I am not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: you need to add the complete error to see what's the problem. but look at the requirements on nokogiri https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri#requirements and look at the installation guide for macos here too
http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 8):

```
brew install libxml2

gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2' -- --use-system-libraries \
  --with-xml2-include=$(brew --prefix libxml2)/include/libxml2
```

[<kbd>Documentation</kbd>](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Answer (score 6):

I recently had to install Nokogiri 1.6.6.2 as well and ran into the same issue (also on Mojave 10.14). I tried installing xcode-select first, but that alone didn't solve it. Further down in the install guide (as @xploshioOn linked https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) is where I found the answer that helped me; installing the extra headers.

> A temporary workaround to allow previous releases of Nokogiri to build is to install the extra headers package mentioned in the Xcode 10 release notes:
>
> `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

That'll open a window where you can then run through the installation prompt for the extra headers to run previous versions of Nokogiri.